# javascript if else statement give the wrong result

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I make a map using `leaflet`, for the map color I'm using dynamic concept where the color is based on the input data, i have 3 data and compare it with each of them for getting the right result, but for some part of the color got the wrong result, this is the `JavaScript` code for the color :

```
data_increase = [5]
data_decrease = [14]
data_equal = [29]
//data is based from input

function color_region_a(fillColor) {
  if (data_increase < data_decrease && data_decrease > data_equal)
    return 'green';
  else if (data_increase < data_decrease && data_decrease < data_equal)
    return '#7FFF00'; //color between green and yellow (Chartreuse)
  else if (data_equal > data_increase && data_equal > data_decrease)
    return 'yellow';
  else if (data_equal > data_increase && data_increase > data_decrease)
    return 'orange';
  else(data_increase > data_decrease && data_increase > data_equal)
  return 'red';
};
```

here's the map part, but i think nothing wrong here :

```
var region_a = L.geoJson(RegionA, {
        "color":"white",
        fillColor: color_region_a(),
        opacity: 10,
    }).addTo(map)
```

The problem is, the function color_region_a `fillColor` result always returning `red`, the result should be `#7FFF00` aka `chartreuse`, where I do it wrong? Or is there any other method that can do what I expect? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is data_increase (and others) an array?

Comment: `data_increase = [5]` creates an array with `5` as value on the first index. However, your if-statement doesn't call a specific index, it's just uses the array instead off a single value

Comment: @jarmod because i need to manipulate it for other purpose

Comment: What do you expect as a result when comparing if an array is greater than another array ..?

Comment: @0stone0 actually, the value of `data_increase` and other is the sum of several lists that I add up, so there is only 1 data in it

Comment: If it needs to be an array then that's fine, but you need to understand how to access the values in the array using `array[index]`. If it doesn't need to be an array then make it a simple numeric value e.g. `const value = 5`.

Comment: @Teemu is to get the fill color on the map that matches the input data

Comment: But you're comparing the wrapper objects of your data, specifically [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), compare the values instead.

Comment: @Teemu you're right, i just comparing the wrapper, it working as you said, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are arrays, which you can't compare as you are.

You need to either make them raw numbers (not in an array) or, compare like:

`data_increase[0] < data_decrease[0]`

Comment: thanks so much @Luke Storry, as you said before, i need to make it to raw numbers In order to be comparable, i tried compare it using `array[index]` it wont work, thanks again for the advice

Answer (score 2):

You have done 2 mistakes.

1. You are comparing `[5] > [29]` which is not correct. You should compare `5 > 29` for this use `data_increase[0] < data_decrease[0]` this way.
2. You forget to add if in last else statement.

See below demo.

```js
data_increase = [5]
data_decrease = [14]
data_equal = [10]
//data is based from input

function color_region_a(fillColor) {
  if (data_increase[0] < data_decrease[0] && data_decrease[0] > data_equal[0])
    return 'green';
  else if (data_increase[0] < data_decrease[0] && data_decrease < data_equal[0])
    return '#7FFF00'; //color between green and yellow (Chartreuse)
  else if (data_equal[0] > data_increase[0] && data_equal[0] > data_decrease[0])
    return 'yellow';
  else if (data_equal[0] > data_increase[0] && data_increase[0] > data_decrease[0])
    return 'orange';
  else if(data_increase[0] > data_decrease[0] && data_increase[0] > data_equal[0])
  return 'red';
};

console.log(color_region_a());
```

Comment: yes, you're correct, i just compare the wrapper, thanks so much for the advice and knowledge. i appreciate it @Vivek Jain